# Free library supporting Gantt charts and granularity <= 1 hour

Tags: java, swing, gantt-chart, granularity

Is there a free graphical library that supports Gantt charts with units of hours or even minutes? I've tried a few. JFreeChart was among the most promising but scaling down seems to reduce the maximum timescale represented to just a few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JFreeChart should be able to go deeper that days.  `SimpleTimePeriod` can represent time down to the millisecond. Might just need to adjust the time display of the axis from the plot.

Comment: Yes. There's just a limit of how many units can be displayed in one go unless mistaken. That might not actually be an issue though as I could add some timescale buttons like in stock charts to change the timescale at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The [nebula solution](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/ganttchart/ganttchart.php) may solve your problem, you have access to the code so you will be able to change something if you need.

Comment: Good find. It apparently supports an hours and minutes view. This is for SWT so I hope it can be integrated into our Swing application.