# Free and easy-to-use PHP library for drawing elegant Gantt Charts

Tags: php, html, gantt-chart

What is the best free and **easy-to-use** PHP library for drawing elegant **Gantt Charts**? I checked [JpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/), but maybe there is any other good option to consider. For instance, [pChart](http://www.pchart.net/) provides nice interface, but it seems it does not allow creating Gantt Charts.

Comment: This does not belong here. sorry.

Comment: Ok,what about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303302/free-library-supporting-gantt-charts-and-granularity-1-hour